# Is there anyway to scrape facebook account links from a list of several hunder URLs

Tags: python, facebook, screen-scraping

I have a list of over 1500 URLs relating to news media sites in India. I was interested in conducting some stats as part of my college project.

Long story short, I was interested in knowing which of these websites have links to their Facebook accounts on their main web page? Doing this would be a tedious task (I have done 25% of them so far), therefore I have been researching via the web on any possibilities of scraping these websites with a program. I have seen scrapers on scraperwiki as well as the `importxml` function primarily in Google Docs, however, thus far I have not been able to achieve much success with either.

I have tried the following function in Google Docs for a given site:

```
=ImportXML(A1, "//a[contains(@href, 'www.facebook.com')]")
```

Overall, I would like to ask whether its even possible (and how) to scan a given website (or list) just for a specific href link if the structure for each website differs significantly?

Thanks in advance for any help regarding this matter.

Mark

Comment: i would recommend you put some of your code here so we can see what you have tried. also if you want to use python, beautifulsoup or regex combined with urllib and urllib2 are the modules you want.

Comment: Beautiful Soup will do a good job with this, but you are potentially looking at the wrong target - the facebook "like" embed for the webpage (or any component there of) as well as any number of other things would contain an href for facebook.com, and NOT a link to the page for the website/user. If you are looking for ANY link to FB, then what you have mentioned as your starting place works, but otherwise you need to be more specific in the results you accept.